# Getting .attr('id').length; of childer input on focus

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add keypad on `.keyboard` with `$('.keyboard').keypad();` to dynamically inserted row. I am inserting row with `$('button[id^="product"]').click()` If i try after this. Its is now working.

```
var count = 1;
$('button[id^="product"]').click(function () {
//adding row to table : WORKING FINE
var leng=$(this).attr('id').length;
var last = $(this).attr('id').substr(leng-4);
var newTr = $('<tr id="row_'+ count + last +'"></tr>');
newTr.html('<td width="29px" style="text-align:center;"><button class="del_row" id="'+ count + last +'" value="'+ item_price +'"> x </button></td><td width="144px"><input type="text" class="code" name="product'+ count +'" value="'+ prod_name +'" /></td><td width="44px" style="text-align:center;"><input class="keyboard" name="quantity'+ count +'" type="text" value="1" id="'+ quan +'"/></td><td style="width: 76px; padding-right: 10px; text-align:right;"><input type="text" class="price" name="price'+ count +'" value="'+ item_price +'" id="'+ pric +'"/></td>');

newTr.appendTo("#saletbl");

count++;         
});

$('.keyboard').keypad({
var leng=$(this).attr('id').length;
var last = $(this).attr('id').substr(leng-4);
}); //not working
```

I tried `.on` table this But not working

```
$("#saletbl").on("focus", ".keyboard", function() {

$('.keyboard').keypad({
var leng=$(this).attr('id').length;
var last = $(this).attr('id').substr(leng-4);
}); //not working

});
```

**If i try inside `$('button[id^="product"]').click()` It is working and showing up keypad**

```
var count = 1;
$('button[id^="product"]').click(function () {
//adding row to table : WORKING FINE

$('.keyboard').keypad({
var leng=$(this).attr('id').length;
var last = $(this).attr('id').substr(leng-4);
}); // working but variable are being changed with parent

count++;         
});
```

My problem is when i add this in main function the variables in `keypad()` are changing with the main functions. I need to change the price of that row if quantity is changed. How can I get `var leng = $(this).attr('id').length;` for `.keyboard` element? I tried `$(this).children().attr('id').length;` But nothing. I need to have `var leng = $(this).attr('id').length;` for each row separately in keyboard function. Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: Dont you think `$('.keyboard').keypad({
var leng=$(this).attr('id').length;
var last = $(this).attr('id').substr(leng-4);
});` is an invalid javascript statement, you are trying to pass javascript statements to a json object.

Comment: I am geting last 4 character of id and it is working fine. But keep changing with parent. I want to know if i can declare keypad() any where else but not in $('button[id^="product"]').click();

Comment: This will never work. You can't declare variables inside of a javascript object like that.

Comment: I found that I can do this in javascript function and then call it in jquery. It is working now. Is it ok if i use it like this?